# BFColorPickerPopover is not disappearing

Tags: popover, nscolorwell

I am trying to use BFColorPickerPopover custom colorwell class. I have an issue with closing Popover. After selecting color Popover window is not disappearing, how can I make it disappear after selecting color?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It behaves as any system popover. You just have to click outside of it to make it close, or press the Escape key.